# How do I make the list detail view using CSS Grid?

Tags: css, css-grid, master-detail

I am using CSS Grid to create a list detail view

- List of items on the left div
- Details shown of each item on the right div
- On desktop both are shown side by side
- On mobile only list is visible by default, when you click on the list item the detail should slide from the right and have a button clicking which will take you back to the list
- [HERE](https://codepen.io/zupkode/pen/jONRVRW) is an actual website that does what I am talking about in mobile view
    [1](https://codepen.io/zupkode/pen/jONRVRW): https://cryptopanic.com/

Html (Pug)

```
html
  head
    title Hello!
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible', content='IE=edge')
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    style.
  body
    #app.container
      header
        h1 CH
      nav
        ul
          li(v-for="item in items" :key="item.feedItemId" @click="showDetails(item)")
            | {{ item.title }}
      main(:class="showDescription ? 'active': 'inactive'") {{ description }}
      footer The footer
```

CSS

```
/**
BASIC HOlY GRAIL LAYOUT SETUP AS PER
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_grid_layout
*/
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header"
    "left   middle"
    "footer footer";
  flex: 1;
  padding: 1em;
  position: relative;
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}

nav {
  grid-area: left;
}

main {
  grid-area: middle;
}


@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "header"
      "left"
      "footer";
  }

  main {
    position: fixed;
  }

  .active {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: -100%;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    z-index: 4;
  }

  .inactive {
    right: 100%;
  }

}

/**
STYLES
*/


/* header,
footer,
nav,
main,
aside {
  border: 1px solid;
} */

nav, main {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

nav > ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav > ul > li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0.75em;
  border: 0.1px solid #eee;
}

main, footer {
  padding: 0.75em;
}
```

JS

```
let items = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  items.push({
    feedItemId: i,
    title: 'Title ' + i,
    description: 'Description ' + i
  });
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      body: "hello from Vue",
      showDescription: false,
      items: items,
      description: 'The main content area'
    };
  },
  methods: {
    showDetails(item) {
      this.description = item.description;
      this.showDescription = !this.showDescription;
    }
  }
});
```

[HERE is the example on CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/zupkode/pen/jONRVRW)